# Why properties of two .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects look different?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-4.7.2

I have a solution with mostly C# Class Library (.NET Framework) projects. I have added a new project to the solution (called **`Training`**) for same the Target Framework (i.e. .NET Framework 4.7.2). But as shown in the screenshot below, if I compare the properties of an old project (called **`Programming`**) w.r.t the new project (called `Training`) then, the different structure of the menu appears (maybe the information is same).

**Question:** Why the Properties information look different for the same project type (class library) and same Target type in Visual Studio 2022?

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the actual project files? I suspect one uses an "SDK-style" project and the other doesn't.

Comment: When you start a new project, type  "class library" in the search box.  Note that there are *two*.  The one labeled ".NET" is the one on the left of the screenshot. ".NET Framework" is one the right, that's the legacy one.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, I am aware of that. As shown in the screenshot, both the projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, that's the case. The older project has `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` specified in the .csproj file. But how do I specify that i want to add a SDK-style project while adding a new project to the solution?

Comment: @skm: Try adding a project targeting .NET 6.0, then editing the csproj file to specify net472.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, worked with this workaround. Thanks :)

Comment: @skm You can invite JonSkeet to turn the comment into an answer and accept it. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Please turn your comment into an answer. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different dialogs are due to the project files being different kinds - there's the "old style" one (which is typically huge and lists every source file) and the "SDK-style" one (which is typically much smaller).

To create a new SDK-style project, target .NET Core or .NET 5+ in the wizard - you can always change the `TargetFramework` property to `net472` or similar later.